# Override CSS set by show()

Tags: jquery

I have a div that am hiding and displaying using jQuery. My function code works properly apart from when I change the div css into `display: inline-block;` to make the div lie side by side another div.

When I click the hide button, the div hides but on clicking the show button, the div does not show. Using Google chrome I inspected the element and noticed this is because jQuery is adding CSS to the div which is `display: block;`. This is making my div not display and is affecting the animation.

Any idea how I can override the CSSjQuery is adding and make jQuery add `display: inline-block` instead of `display: block;` without affecting the animation? My code is here
CSS:

```
#taskList-right {
    width: 48%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 7px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#package_buttn").click(function () {
    if ($("#taskList-right").is(":hidden")) {
        console.log('passed here');
        // $("#taskList-right").slideDown();//this function should slide the div down but is commented for bug tracking.
        $("#taskList-right").show();
    } 
    else {
        $("#taskList-right").slideUp();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you using display:inline-block when your divs are floating (float:right)?

Comment: Can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net which shows the problem. As @simplyray says, it's little odd using both `float` and `inline-block`

Comment: if I don't put it that way, the two divs will not lie side by side how I want them.

Comment: @Ukavi: Works for me in the normal case: http://jsbin.com/uciyed/1 FWIW

Comment: @T.J.Crowder your css is on the element, mine is in an external sheet. Anyway I've fixed it that way with a   display: inline-block ! important;

Comment: @Ukavi: My styling is **not** "on the element," it's applied via CSS just like yours is. It makes zero difference whether you apply a style in a `<style>` element or via an external stylesheet and a `<link>`. (It would matter if my styling were "on" the element, e.g., a `style` attribute.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with some amendments like:

make a css class

```
.inlineBlock{   
    display:inline-block;
}
```

and then:

```
$("#package_buttn").click(function () {
  if ($("#taskList-right").is(":hidden")) {
    console.log('passed here');
    $("#taskList-right").addClass('inlineBlock');
  } else {
    $("#taskList-right").slideUp().removeClass('inlineBlock');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding required display style using css function.

```
$("#taskList-right").css('display','inline-block');
```